# Not able to call the the method of the child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following components .

this component accept props which is function that can be called.

```
deleteIcon = () => {
 console.log("deleting the document");
}

    export const Parent = (props) => {

      return (
         <button onclick={() => {deleteIcon()}}
      )

    }
```

Now, I have some another component which uses this component. which has its own implementation of the deleteIcon method.

```
deletechildIcon = () => {

}

export const child = () => {
     return (
   <Parent deleteIcon={() => {deletechildIcon()}} />
 )
}
```

So, from child still it is calling the parent method and not the child one. can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notice points:

- **onClick** rather than `onclick`
- no need to use arrow function inside props, which may cause performance loss and it's not the best practice
- write your functions inside the component
- `Child` component is the one which been called inside the `Parent`, you made it the opposite

---

Try the demo in-text:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const deleteIcon = () => {
    console.log("deleting the document");
  };
  return <Child deleteIcon={deleteIcon} />;
};

const Child = props => {
  return <button onClick={props.deleteIcon}>XXX</button>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, I am facing one more issue .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059198/material-ui-formcontrollabel-whole-label-is-clickable-only-text-should-be could u please check

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the deleteIcon method in your Parent component, not the props.deleteIcon

Comment: yeah but the thing is that  parent has to call parents method only

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `Parent` to have a default `deleteIcon` prop that can be optionally overridden in specific implementations. You could do that by editing `Parent` like so:

```
deleteIcon = () => {
 console.log("deleting the document");
}

export const Parent = (props) => {
  const buttonOnClickHandler = props.deleteIcon || deleteIcon;
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {buttonOnClickHandler()}}
  )
}
```

Or you could use default arguments:

```
deleteIconDefault = () => {
 console.log("deleting the document");
}

export const Parent = ({
  deleteIcon = deleteIconDefault
}) => {;
  return (
      <button onClick={() => {this.props.deleteIcon()}}
  )
}
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!