# Material-UI formControlLabel whole label is clickable only text should be

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to the `material UI`. here I have the following `form`

```html
<FormControl
  variant="outlined"
  className={css.formControl}
  margin="dense"
  key={"abc_" + index}
>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={
      <Checkbox
        onClick={handleClick(data)}
        checked={_.some(selected, { Id: selected.Id })}
        value={selected.Id}
        color="default"
      />
    }
    label={data?.Name ?? "NO_LABEL"}
  />
</FormControl>
```

Now, this whole label gets clickable as the area is a bit long, so, what I am trying is the only the checkbox and the text should be clickable and the other empty space should not be clicked. Here , I have given the

```
max-width for that label to be 272px.
```

How do I add that?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem of having empty space after the text that is clickable. I suspect this may have something to do with the CSS in your `css.formControl` class (probably setting an explicit width?).

Answer (score 8):

You can prevent parent elements from click events, as well as allow the child to do it.

Use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to disable click event.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

```html
<FormControlLabel
  style={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}
  control={
    <Checkbox
      onClick={handleClick}
      style={{ pointerEvents: "auto" }}
      color="default"
    />
  }
  label={"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question, as I think they were asking how to disable the click on the right of the text

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I understood OP's question as: Clicking on the checkbox should work, clicking on the text of the label should work, but clicking on the empty space at the right of the text should not work. This is due to flexbox that makes the label take all available space.

Comment: @AlexandreS Yes you are right, that was a misunderstanding by me, since the answer has got some up-votes, I shall keep it here but you can also make your comment an answer!

Answer (score 5):

This will do

```
MuiFormControlLabel: {
              styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                  width: "fit-content"
                }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with those checkboxes, see here:
[image: checkboxes]
With dev tools:
[image]

The label takes whole space (purple space).

That is due to the FormGroup displaying children in a column flex container.

To fix it, in my custom overloaded checkbox, I used:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import MUICheckbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

const useFormGroupStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'block',
  },
});

const Checkbox = (props) => {
  const { onCheck } = props;
  const formGroupClasses = useFormGroupStyles();
  const checkbox = (
    <MUICheckbox
      onChange={event => onCheck(event, event.target.checked)}
      icon={props.uncheckedIcon}
      checkedIcon={props.checkedIcon}
      color="primary"
      style={props.style}
    />
  );
  return (
    <FormGroup classes={formGroupClasses}>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={checkbox}
        label={props.label}
        style={props.style}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```